# Why is the domain of $F(t) = t^t$ for $ t \gt 0$ for all real numbers?

Tags: calculus

If you test values negatives values and even $0$ for $t$, you still get values for them.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that $t^t$ is easily calculated to be a real number for negative *integers*, but that's not representative of the general case for negative vales of $t$. You can even find a real value for $t^t$ when $t$ is a negative rational with odd denominator, but that's the extent to which you get a real number as an answer.

Because you can't extend the domain to an *interval* of negative numbers (and still map into $\mathbb{R}$), we usually restrict to positive reals.

Also, you can't include $0$ in the domain in any case. The expression $0^0$ can't be defined in a consistent manner. That's because $t^0=1$ for $t>0$, but $0^t=0$ for $t>0$. So $0^0$ can't agree with both of these.

Answer (score 1):

Taking negatives to arbitrary powers is not as simple as it seems. To do so properly, you need a bit of complex analysis and a redefinition of what it means to take a power a la $a^b \equiv e^{b\log a}$.

Answer (score 0):

The complex log is a subtle creation and it can be dangerous when used without real understanding. Hence $t > 0$.